# NetBeans Cache in Linux

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Within my Linux there is a folder `~/.cache/netbeans/8.0` which is 12 GB large. Why is this folder so large and do I need this cache? Can I simply delete it to free space? Do I need to backup it when I move to another computer?

Answer (score 0):

This is folder where NetBeans stores all information "temporary" information, such as local history (local, not svn/git/hg...), indexes for projects (used for e.g. code completion etc.), heap dumps... You can remove it (and lose e.g. local history) and then NetBeans will create it again and will continue to store information there as needed.

In theory in could happen that the cache contain no longer relevant information (from unused projects for example) but if you do remove it, it will need to re-scan and re-parse your opened projects, which will take some time so you might have to wait for this to finish before getting IDE to working state as it was before.

More information http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir